# How can I hide an element loaded via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a script which uses AJAX to retrieve information from a php file called names.php.

Further down the script i use JQuery's $(document.ready(function(){}); to try to hide a div on DOM load.

For some reason the $("div").hide() function does not execute after the AJAX call.

Can anyone help me understand why? I know that after an AJAX call you must bind elements to their event handlers but im wondering how its possible to right after the page loads.

My script

**index.html**

```
<body onload="getNames()">
```

**JQuery script**

```
function getNames()
{
    function AJAX()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "names.php",
            data: namesVariables,
            success: function (retrievedData) 
            {
                console.log(retrievedData);
                jQuery("div").html(retrievedData);
            }
        });    
    }
}

$(  document ).ready(function()
{
        $("div").hide();
});
```

Comment: Where and how do you call AJAX() - just declaring a function does not run it

Comment: That code should work fine, assuming the div you are trying to target exists on dom ready.

Comment: @mplungjan That would be never. Besides, declaring `AJAX()` (which uses a jQuery selector) outside the jQuery code block might not help.

Comment: I tihnig you need call your AJAX() method.

Comment: anything in doc.ready executes on page ready. your ajax is asynchronous and isn't called.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry the AJAX function is called by event handler on a button. I will include this now though as a revision

Comment: If you're attempting to hide an element that is created by `jQuery("div").html(retrievedData);`, then put `$("div").hide();` after it in your `success` function

Comment: @PatrickQ this is my accepted solution. Another user pointed this out as an answer but if you do the same i will accept your answer as it was presented first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're attempting to hide an element that is created by `jQuery("div").html(retrievedData);`, then put `$("div").hide();` after it in your `success` function

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying do this:

```
$(  document ).ready(function()
{
    $("div").hide();
    AJAX();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this ?

```
function AJAX()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "names.php",
            data: namesVariables,
            success: function (retrievedData) 
            {
                console.log(retrievedData);
                jQuery("div").html(retrievedData);
                $("div").hide();
            }
        });    
    }
```